# Why does equals() in Java must be passed Object as a parameter?

Tags: java, object, hashmap, equals, hashcode

When we override the `equals()` method in Java, I know that `Object` needs to be a parameter, but I wonder - why `Object`?.

Second, let us say we override `hashcode()` and implement `equals()`, but set the parameter in `equals()` to `MyClass` instead of `Object` (`MyClass` being the class whose `equals()` method we override). Will we still get the expected behavior if we use `HashMap`?

Update: Yes, it will be overloading instead of overriding. But what will happen if we use `HashMap` with overloaded `equals()`? Also, I don't find the answer in related posts. Or is it something obvious that I am missing?

Comment: "implement equals() but set the parameter in equals() to MyClass instead of Object" --> then you are not overriding `equals`.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure whether the linked URL answers the OP question about why Object is a parameter

Comment: @seteropere I just went through it but I too didn't find the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you write an equals() method whose parameter is not Object, you are overloading the method, not overriding it.

Now, as for `HashMap` - `HashMap` calls equals to compare keys. The type of the compared keys is `Object`. Therefore, if you define an `equals()` method with a parameter whose not `Object`, this method will be ignored by `HashMap`.

I tried the following code :

```
public class SomeClass
{
    int privateMember;

    // note it's important to override hashCode, since if the hashCode of two
    // keys is not the same, equals() won't be called at all
    public int hashCode ()
    {
        return privateMember;
    }

    public boolean equals (Object other)
    {
        if (other instanceof SomeClass) {
            return this.privateMember==((SomeClass)other).privateMember;
        }
        else { 
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        HashMap<SomeClass,String> map = new HashMap<SomeClass,String>();
        SomeClass s1 = new SomeClass ();
        SomeClass s2 = new SomeClass ();
        s1.priv=4;
        s2.priv=4;
        map.put (s1, "something");
        if (map.containsKey (s2)) {
            System.out.println ("found!");
        } else {
            System.out.println ("not found!");
        }
    }
}
```

This code outputs "found!".

Now, if you run the exact same code, but replace the `equals` method with :

```
    public boolean equals (SomeClass other)
    {
        if (other instanceof SomeClass) {
            return this.privateMember==((SomeClass)other).privateMember;
        }
        else { 
            return false;
        }
    }
```

The output will be "not found!", which means our `equals` method was ignored.

Comment: Indeed, but will we have same unexpected behavior with HashMap as mentioned in the linked URL?

Comment: Definitely. The HashMap needs something which is connected to Object.equals which must take an input of type Object.

Comment: Thanks to Eran and Ashley-frieze for your answers. Helps a lot.I think I get the idea now.

Answer (score 0):

The collections use the equals and hashcode methods from the Object base class. Therefore you must override them in order for your custom class to provide an implementation. You can overload equals if you wish, and that would work for situations where some code knows that it's dealing with an instance of `MyClass`. However, this would be misleading.

All the collections classes are designed to work with instances of Object and Object provides a general purpose equals method.

You shouldn't really need to write an equals method directly. You can either generate one using your IDE, or use EqualsBuilder from Apache Commons (https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/EqualsBuilder.html) to help put it all together.